# Custom Slack Command with AWS API Gateway - 500_service_error

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, slack, slack-api

I'd developing a custom Slack command returning response from an Amazon lambda via API Gateway. Everything was working well when suddenly I couldn't make any call without returning

```
'Darn - that slash command didn't work (error message: `500_service_error`
```

Via Curl, the response status is '200' and I'm still receiving correctly the json response of my lambda.

- Do you have any idea a potential origin of this bug?
- Is there any way to be able to debug custom App for Slack?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discussed with the Slack team that can check their internal logs for you:

> "Unfortunately we don't have a debug console available for developers
>   just yet"
>
> "I can confirm that Slack is receiving a 500 server error when
>   connecting to your Slash command endpoint. Unfortunately I don't
>   really have any more information from our end"

The real problem is the transformation of the call body from form to json at the level of the API Gateway. Slack is sending a form body that has to be transformed in json for the lamda. I was following this thread  https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=673012&tstart=0#673012:

- But depending on the information that Slack was sending, it could break sometimes with certain parameter characters
- I have updated the AWS template to fix my API Gateway issues https://gist.github.com/vpasquier/ecded1546c0b736ecf4a5670b4328269

It will be nice in future to have the logs of the Slack features, to have JSON payload instead of form and in the same time to enable directly the Cloudwatch logs for API Gateway in order to check random bugs :)

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution you worked out with the Slack support team for your specific problem. But in the absence of a debug feature on Slack the only currently available debug option is to simulate a Slack request to your app with the approach I described in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like an issues in your app. If you want to test your app you can just simulate the POST request Slack sends when you invoke the command.

That can be done with a simple HTML form or if you want something more advanced use https://www.hurl.it/ or [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/). Hurl is a webpage and postman is a desktop app. Both allow you to send custom GET and POST requests to any URL. Postman is the more advanced solution that allows structured testing.

See below for an example POST request from Slack for slash commands (from the [offical documentatio](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands)). Obviously you will want to adjust it to fit your configuration.

```
token=gIkuvaNzQIHg97ATvDxqgjtO
team_id=T0001
team_domain=example
enterprise_id=E0001
enterprise_name=Globular%20Construct%20Inc
channel_id=C2147483705
channel_name=test
user_id=U2147483697
user_name=Steve
command=/weather
text=94070
response_url=https://hooks.slack.com/commands/1234/5678
```

To your other point. If you want concrete help you on your specific issue you need to post your code.

Comment: Or Curl is working well too :) I'm in discussion with the Slack team now. It was working when returning a string. I have changed several things in the Slack configuration console for my app so I will post details of the resolution here soon after understanding. Thank you for your help.

Comment: My answer below, I have edited my question too in case other people need it